# which one is correct in this sentence, “To” or “in”?

Tags: prepositions

Should I use “in” instead of “to”?
The leopardess was weakly stumbling **to** the opposite direction of the gun sound

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to use 'The leopardess was weakly stumbling *away from* the gun sound'

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the correct usage is 'in the opposite direction'. When there is an endpoint or milestone, you could say: 'the leopardess was weakly stumbling to a shelter'. 
A direction has no ending though, you could be walking on forever, so you wouldn't be walking to(wards) anything.